# zipkin Unable to establish connection to RabbitMQ server

Tags: rabbitmq, zipkin

I tried in Windows 10 machine to coonect RabbitMQ (3.6.11 version installed with Erlang 20) to ZipKin, but I got the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'armeriaServer' defined in com.linecorp.armeria.spring.ArmeriaAutoConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'armeriaServer' parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverConfigurator' defined in zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinHttpConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'serverConfigurator' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkin2.server.internal.health.ZipkinHealthController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitMq' defined in zipkin2.server.internal.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: Unable to establish connection to RabbitMQ server: Connection refused: connect
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.7.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at zipkin.server.ZipkinServer.main(ZipkinServer.java:54) [classes!/:?]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [zipkin-server-2.21.5-exec.jar:?]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) [zipkin-server-2.21.5-exec.jar:?]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [zipkin-server-2.21.5-exec.jar:?]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [zipkin-server-2.21.5-exec.jar:?]

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverConfigurator' defined in zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinHttpConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'serverConfigurator' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkin2.server.internal.health.ZipkinHealthController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitMq' defined in zipkin2.server.internal.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: Unable to establish connection to RabbitMQ server: Connection refused: connect

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkin2.server.internal.health.ZipkinHealthController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitMq' defined in zipkin2.server.internal.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: Unable to establish connection to RabbitMQ server: Connection refused: connect

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitMq' defined in zipkin2.server.internal.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: Unable to establish connection to RabbitMQ server: Connection refused: connect

> Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Unable to establish connection to RabbitMQ server: Connection refused: connect

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just resolved this issue ..

Step1.verify C:\Programfiles\Err(version) folder including bin folder is created or not. Otherwise try to download and install Erlang again. reinstall RabbitMQ and try connecting Zipkin. Make sure Erlang version and RabbitMQ version is compatible.

Step2.Check ERLANG_HOME is set to proper location in environment variables.

at this point if RabbitMQ windows installer pointing to any old erlang version installed earlier  try to install RabitMQ windows manually
follow the steps mentioned in below link for manual installation

https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html